# cin input not completely read in C++

Tags: c++

I am learning to program C++ using the book by Lippman et al Fifth edition. I have to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"
int main()
{

    int book;
    {
        std::cin>>book;
        std::cout<<book<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `int book` declaration is on my own. I am not sure but I created a header file named "Sales_item" within the project. The book does not say anything else. The header file pops up with the next code inside it:

```
#ifndef SALES_ITEM_H_INCLUDED
#define SALES_ITEM_H_INCLUDED



#endif // SALES_ITEM_H_INCLUDED
```

The goal of the project is to input an ISBN, its price and the number of books sold and the output is supposed to display the total revenue for that ISBN. However, When I enter the data, it only writes in the output 9 digits.

I do not pretend that you solve everything for me. I would greatly appreciate any help, some book recommendations and so on.

Should I modify on my own the header file?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: The book comes with some source code, including a file called `Sales_item.h`. Is that what you're looking for? I don't really understand your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: @Pavel Please don't recommend the cplusplus.com tutorial. It's a discouraged resource to learn C++ with. The majority of people in the C++ tag typically point people to read a book instead.

Comment: @Pavel remove your comment. :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a limit to the value an `int` can hold. In a 32-bits architecture, an `int` can only hold values ranging from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

You say it "only" outputs 9 digits, obviously you are trying to store a number that is just too big to be stored in an `int`.

Try using `int64_t` or handle this serial number as a `std::string`.

`int64_t` can hold values from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 and should suffice to store the 13 digits of an ISBN.

Comment: what about ISBNs with `X` in them?

Comment: I have done that and it worked! However, why does the author include the Sales_item.h directive? Besides this, when I type three different prices, lets say 20, 21, 22, the output is something in millions like 9659400 (it does not matter if I enter prices like 5,7,8, the output is the same) and I really do not understand why is giving to me this value.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ISBN, I suppose you will have to Google that stuff out.

Comment: the ISBN output works fine after your recommendation.I mean the problem is with the average price after I enter three different values.